# Can't sync time between domain controller and another servers/computers (windows 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, time-synchronization

Good morning,
We have domain controller on windows server 2003 and another windows 2003 servers with terminal server and DB and regular workstations. Today in Israel we returned back to winter time (one hour back), domain controller now shows current time but all another machines in network show different time they went two hour back and there's difference in one hour between domain controller and another machines.
I have tried to perform W32tm /resync /update but without success, where can be problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the clients and server have the same Daylight Saving Time and Time Zone configuration?

Comment: Regarding same time zone - yes. Regarding daylight saving time don't, checkbox automatically adjust daylight saving time is checked, all patches applied but I haven't check it manually through the registry yet.

Comment: run nltest /server:servername /dsgetdc:domainname.company.com.  In the FLAGS section, it should state TIMESERV.  That will tell you if your DC is actually advertising as a time server.  It typically looks like this:  GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLOSE_SITE.

Comment: Yes, the output was: Flags: PDC GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV GTIMESERV WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLOSE_SITE
Also if I perform w32tm /monitor from another computer it shows that it synchronized with DC server.

Comment: I also run w32tm -tz and output very strange : Time zone: Current:TIME_ZONE_ID_STANDARD Bias: -120min (UTC=LocalTime+Bias)
  [Standard Name:"Jerusalem Standard Time" Bias:0min Date:(M:9 D:4 DoW:0)]
  [Daylight Name:"Jerusalem Daylight Time" Bias:-60min Date:(M:3 D:5 DoW:5)]
How can I understand it? M is month, D is day but what does it mean DoW? BTW it's output from my home machine (not in AD) and it shows right time. But should it be (M:9 D:22 DoW:0) and not (M:9 D:4 DoW:0) ?

Comment: Can you confirm the PDC Emulator FSMO role is on a current working DC?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this may have something to do with it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Summer_Time

```
Summer time start and end dates 2007-2016

Year     begins      ends
2007    30 March    16 September
2008    28 March    5 October
2009    27 March    27 September
2010    26 March    12 September
2011    1 April     2 October
2012    30 March    23 September
2013    29 March    8 September
2014    28 March    28 September
2015    27 March    20 September
2016    1 April     9 October
```

"In the past, the unpredictability of DST in Israel became frustrating enough that Microsoft Windows stopped trying to track changes and just made Israeli time be Greenwich Mean Time plus two hours (GMT+2) (and disabled the daylight saving option). This has led to various ad hoc solutions to the problem in Windows systems and other Microsoft software (e.g. Outlook calendar entries are often off by an hour when shared, due to the lack of DST support). On November 17, 2009, Microsoft released an update that has daylight saving time enabled for Israel. However, the date for transition back to Standard Time is set as the Second Sunday of September, regardless of the Hebrew Calendar date.[2] Windows 7 does contain correct DST times up to 2023, but not all software makes use of this extra information."

Here is what I show on my Windows 7/2008 R2 machines for Israel.  You may want to compare this with yours.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Israel Standard Time]
"MUI_Display"="@tzres.dll,-370"
"MUI_Dlt"="@tzres.dll,-371"
"MUI_Std"="@tzres.dll,-372"
"Display"="(UTC+02:00) Jerusalem"
"Dlt"="Jerusalem Daylight Time"
"Std"="Jerusalem Standard Time"
"TZI"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,00,00,01,00,02,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,05,00,01,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Israel Standard Time\Dynamic DST]
"FirstEntry"=dword:000007d4
"LastEntry"=dword:000007e7
"2004"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2005"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,00,00,02,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,05,00,01,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2006"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,00,00,01,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2007"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,03,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2008"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,00,00,01,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2009"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,05,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2010"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,02,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2011"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,00,00,01,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,05,00,01,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2012"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,04,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2013"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,02,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2014"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,04,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2015"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,03,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2016"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,00,00,02,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,05,00,01,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2017"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,04,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2018"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,03,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2019"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,00,00,01,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2020"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,04,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2021"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,09,00,00,00,02,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,05,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2022"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,00,00,01,00,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,05,00,01,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"2023"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```